# How long does it take to restore a disabled Facebook account?

Tags: facebook

How long will it take to get back my Facebook account? I have submitted my PAN card as I didn’t have my ID card. So when will Facebook reply about the verification process? It’s been three days and I haven’t received any reply yet.

Comment: How long did it take in the end? It's been almost a week for me, also without any reply. I sent an email to appeals@facebook as that was my only recourse, but I was never actually banned: I'm locked out by a silly Facebook bug.